# Sublime Text 4. Отмена key binding с определенным действием

Tags: sublime-text, sublime-text-4

На клавишу `tab` завязано много действий. Каждое содержит свой `context`

Я хочу отменить одно действие из всех.
В инете нашел только варианты полностью отключить все действия для клавиши, а мне нужно отменить только одно:

```
{ "keys": ["tab"], "command": "commit_completion", "context":
    [{ "key": "auto_complete_visible" }]
},
```

P.S.

Если честно, это ужас какой-то.
По табу ты прыгаешь (прыгал) по меткам в новой конструкции, например foreach

```
foreach($mark as $mark => $mark) {
    $mark
}
```

То есть

`ввел значение - таб - ввел значение - таб`

быстро и удобно

Теперь по табу **всегда** выбирается что-то из автозаполнения и это превращается в

`ввел значение - эскейп - эскейп - эскейп - навел мышью или клавишей в нужное место - ввел значение - эскейп - эскейп - эскейп`

Обидно